# Filtering chain issue with ActiveRecord and Arel (SQL)

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, activerecord

Here is the set up:

```rb
class Title
  has_many :managed_rights
end
```

```rb
class ManagedRight
  belongs_to :title
  has_many :managed_right_countries
  enumerize :territory_rights, in: [:all, :include, :exclude], default: :all
end
```

```rb
class ManagedRightCountry
  belongs_to :managed_right
  belongs_to :country
end
```

```rb
class Country; end
```

**I want to filter titles by countries, where `country_ids = [3, 5, 8, 9]`.**

- All case
  If `title.managed_rights[0].territory_rights == :all` selecting this title
- If include case
  selects only if any of the `managed_right_countries` is in the `country_ids`, otherwise skips.

```rb
title.managed_rights[0].territory_rights == :include 
AND title.managed_rights[0].managed_right_countries IN country_ids
```

- If exclude case
  selects all titles, except where any of `managed_right_countries` is in the `country_ids`.

```rb
title.managed_rights[0].territory_rights == :exclude
AND title.managed_rights[0].managed_right_countries ALL NOT IN country_ids
```

That's what I've tried with Arel:

```rb
managed_rights = ManagedRight.arel_table
managed_right_countries = ManagedRightCountry.arel_table

Title.left_outer_joins(managed_rights: :managed_right_countries)
  .where(
    # some other filters not related to "managed_rights"
    managed_rights[:territory_rights].eq(:all)
      .or(
        managed_rights[:territory_rights].eq(:include)
        .and(managed_right_countries[:country_id].in(country_ids))
        .or(
          managed_rights[:territory_rights].eq(:exclude)
          .and(managed_right_countries[:country_id].not_in(country_ids))
        )
      )
  ).distinct
```

It works for most cases, except when `managed_right_countries.country_id` has some IDs which are not in the `country_ids` array. Meaning with the query above `:exclude` works only when all countries are in the array.
But I need to exclude title from the result if ANY country is in the array.

**How can I do it so it works properly?**

Preferably with AREL but raw SQL(PostgreSQL) could also work if there is no way to do it with Arel only.

**Example:**

```
title_01 has `managed_rights[0].territory_rights = :all`
title_02 has `managed_rights[0].territory_rights = :include`
         and `managed_rights[0].managed_right_countries = [1, 2]`
title_03 has `managed_rights[0].territory_rights = :exclude`
         and `managed_rights[0].managed_right_countries = [2, 3]`
```

- When filter by countries [1] all 3 titles should be selected (1 is included for title_02 and is not excluded from title_03)
- When by countries [2] only title_01 and title_02 should be selected (since three third one is excluded)
- When by countries [3] only title_01 should be selected since 3 is not included for title_02 and is excluded for title_03
- If filter by empty countries [] all three should be shown

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved by creating a nested subquery.

SQL solution:

```sql
SELECT titles.* FROM titles
LEFT OUTER JOIN managed_rights ON managed_rights.title_id = titles.id
LEFT OUTER JOIN managed_right_countries ON managed_right_countries.managed_right_id = managed_rights.id
WHERE (titles.rights = 'all' OR managed_rights.title_id is NULL)
OR managed_rights.territory_rights = 'all'
OR (
    managed_rights.territory_rights = 'include' AND managed_right_countries.country_id in (country_ids)
)
OR (
    managed_rights.territory_rights = 'exclude' 
        AND NOT titles.id in (
            SELECT titles.id FROM titles
            LEFT OUTER JOIN managed_rights ON managed_rights.title_id = titles.id
            LEFT OUTER JOIN managed_right_countries ON managed_right_countries.managed_right_id = managed_rights.id
            WHERE managed_rights.territory_rights = 'exclude' 
                AND managed_right_countries.country_id in (country_ids)
        )
)
```

AREL solution:

```rb
titles = Title.arel_table
managed_rights = ManagedRight.arel_table
managed_right_countries = ManagedRightCountry.arel_table

excluded_title_ids = titles.project('titles.id')
  .join(managed_rights, Arel::Nodes::OuterJoin)
  .on(managed_rights[:title_id].eq(titles[:id]))
  .join(managed_right_countries, Arel::Nodes::OuterJoin)
  .on(managed_right_countries[:managed_right_id].eq(managed_rights[:id]))
  .where(
    managed_rights[:territory_rights].eq(:exclude)
      .and(managed_right_countries[:country_id].in(available_countries))
  )

Title.left_outer_joins(managed_rights: :managed_right_countries)
  .where(
    managed_rights[:territory_rights].eq(:all)
    .or(
      managed_rights[:territory_rights].eq(:include)
        .and(managed_right_countries[:country_id].in(available_countries))
        .or(
          managed_rights[:territory_rights].eq(:exclude)
          .and(titles[:id].not_in(excluded_title_ids))
        )
    )
  )
```